# Concurrent object destruction

Tags: c++, destructor, language-lawyer

I have misunderstandingn on sec. 3.6.3/1 N3797. When I considered initialization rule I come across with copy-initialization concept.

> If the completion of the constructor
>   or dynamic initialization of an object with static storage duration is
>   sequenced before that of another, the completion of the destructor of
>   the second is sequenced before the initiation of the destructor of the
>   first. [ Note: **This definition permits concurrent destruction.**— end
>   note ]

Is it possible that completion destructors of the second and of the first are in different threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** I edited and corrected the statement about unsequenced initialization (thanks to @dyp). If your program doesn't start any threads, then all initializations happen in some (possibly indeterminate) sequence.

---

There are no constraints beyond the constraints described in the Standard<sup>1</sup> on which threads perform initialization and destruction of objects with static storage duration. In particular, the initialization of objects in different translation units are indeterminately sequenced with respect to one another (cf. [basic.start.init]/2), and *unsequenced* if the program starts threads.

It is therefore possible for initializations to occur concurrently in multiple threads if the first function call within a TU occurs within another thread other than the main thread. What the standard says is that those objects whose initialization *is* sequenced (e.g. those in the same TU) are also destroyed in a deterministic, compatible order.

<sub>**______________**

1) "beyond what is said, nothing is said" — a bit it of a tautology, but worth calling out</sub>

Comment: @dyp: You're saying that it would be invalid for the program to run all the global initializers in one thread per TU, join them all and then call `main`?

Comment: That is there is no more restriction other than completion of the second and initiation of the first must be in the same thread.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv: Not even - the second just has to *happen-before* the first.

Comment: @dyp: I believe that [basic.start.init]/2 says that neither A is sequenced before B nor is B sequenced before A. They're genuinely *unsequenced*.

Comment: @dyp: Oh, right, it's only unsequenced *if* the program starts a thread. Right, so otherwise a sequence has to be established by the hosting environment.

Comment: Note that there's an additional interesting guarantee about block-scope variables with static storage duration; see http://stackoverflow.com/q/24589190/420683

Comment: @dyp: Yeah, neat. Thanks. Everything is basically "what you think it should be" in order for a recursive, well-founded program to make sense. It just gets a bit verbose at times when you're dealing with all the details.

Comment: It's a bit unclear. _Sequenced before is an asymmetric, transitive, pair-wise relation between evaluations executed by a **single thread**_ Completion of the second is _sequenced_ before initiation of the first. This implies that they are in the same thread. Where I'm wrong?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv Uhhh.. this basically means, as far as I can tell, that when there are two threads concurrently initializing variables in different TUs, and one thread observes the values stored/side effects performed by the other thread, then those changes of values/side effects appear in an indeterminate order for the observing thread (but never concurrently).

Comment: @DmitryFucintv: I think you only get the sequencing guarantee if programs start no threads. In that case it's reasonable to assume they all happen in the same thread, or in any case something indistinguishable from that.